# Source code files location for wrap

Tags: oracle, encryption, location

I want to encrypt a package code.

For do that, I want to use the wrap command.

So for example I have that package:

> wrap_try

and when I'm executing that command:

```
C:\Users\dp>wrap iname=wrap_try.sql
```

I'm getting that output:

```
PL/SQL Wrapper: Release 11.2.0.4.0- 64bit Production on Thu May 11 12:59:50 2017

Copyright (c) 1993, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

PL/SQL Wrapper error: Couldn't open input file wrap_try.sql
```

So I guess it's can't found my file because i need to give it a full path.

But what is the location of all the package\function definition?

My server is windows.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First extract your procedure source to a file, which in your case is 'wrap_try.sql'. Then run your command on the file.dir,

```
D:\prog>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 421D-3389

 Directory of D:\prog

05/11/2017  08:04 AM    <DIR>          .
05/11/2017  08:04 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/11/2017  08:02 AM            30,609 customer_extract_proc.sql
               1 File(s)         30,609 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  237,137,584,128 bytes free

D:\prog>wrap iname=customer_extract_proc.sql

PL/SQL Wrapper: Release 11.2.0.4.0- 64bit Production on Thu May 11 08:05:02 2017

Copyright (c) 1993, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Processing customer_extract_proc.sql to customer_extract_proc.plb

D:\prog>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 421D-3389

 Directory of D:\prog

05/11/2017  08:05 AM    <DIR>          .
05/11/2017  08:05 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/11/2017  08:05 AM             5,661 customer_extract_proc.plb
05/11/2017  08:02 AM            30,609 customer_extract_proc.sql
               2 File(s)         36,270 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  237,137,575,936 bytes free
```